# Why does installing python-minimal package also grab the python package on Debian?

Tags: debian, package-management, apt, python

From running:

```
apt-cache depends python2.6-minimal | grep Depends
```

and

```
apt-cache depends python2.6 | grep Depends
```

it looks like `python2.6` depends on `python2.6-minimal` and a lot more.

However, when I run, `apt-get install python2.6-minimal` it tries to install the same packages as when I run `apt-get install python2.6` -- both warns `17.0 MB of additional disk space will be used`. Why is this happening?

P.S.

Another funky thing that seems to happen is that when I try to install the python package, it wants `18.0 MB of additional disk space`. But

```
apt-cache depends python | grep Depends
```

only shows

```
Depends: python2.6
Depends: python-minimal
```

Why does `python` require a megabyte more than `python2.6`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you are having extra package installations, is because of `python-minimal`'s recommends.  `apt-get` has been configured to automatically install all recommended packages, when you install a new package.   You can tell `apt-get` to not install recommended packages like this.

```
apt-get install --no-install-recommends python2.6-minimal
```

Just remember... When you don't install recommends, you might not get all the functionality.   Often people assume you always install recommends, then they have no idea why some installed package throws errors.  The problem is most recommends should really be suggests, which has made recommends somewhat useless.  Most of the time I install without recommends, and it only results in unexpected behavior occasionally.  Any package that is not system or desktop critical, usually can be installed without recommends.

I hope I was able to help,

Answer (score 2):

`python-minimal` recommends `python`.

```
% apt-cache depends python-minimal
python-minimal
  Depends: python2.7-minimal
  Depends: dpkg
    dpkg:i386
  Recommends: python
  Conflicts: python-central
  Conflicts: <python-central:i386>
  Breaks: idle
...
```

By default, `apt-get` installs recommendations automatically. Try

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends python-minimal
```

Answer (score 1):

As well as the other suggestions, you can also disable automatic bundling of recommends globally by adding a file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d` with the statement `APT::Install-Recommends "0";`.